# Convergence of $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt \ln x} \mathrm { d}x$ by Asymptotic Comparison Test.

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals

According to the material I have,
If $f:[a,b)\to \mathbb{R} ,b\in \mathbb{R},f\geq0 $
Then:
**i)** If $f$ is an infinite function of real order $\alpha\lt1$ with respect to $\frac {1}{x-b}$ $\implies$ $\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm { d}x\lt\infty$
**ii)** If $f$ is an infinite function of real order $\alpha\geq1$ with respect to $\frac {1}{x-b}$ $\implies$ $\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm { d}x=\infty$
Based on this information I am trying to evaluate the convergence of $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt \ln x} \mathrm { d}x$
In order to determine the order of my function I consider $$\lim_{x\to1+}{\frac{1}{\sqrt\ln x \over\frac{1}{(x-2)^\alpha}}}=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac {(x-2)^\alpha}{\sqrt\ln x}$$
Despite trying various methods I haven't been able to obtain a real number as a limit value for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*An issue is that you look at $b=2$. You should consider the fact that the "problem" is at $1$, and adapt your theorem (it's easy) for $f\colon (a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and look at the $a=1$  end.*

Rewrite, for $x>1$,
$$
\sqrt{\ln x} =  \sqrt{\ln(1+(x-1))}\,.
$$
This seems silly, but now, recall that
$$
\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\ln(1+u)}{u} = 1
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt{\ln x}}{(x-1)^{1/2}} = \lim_{x\to 1} \sqrt{\frac{\ln x}{x-1}}= \lim_{x\to 1} \sqrt{\frac{\ln(1+(x-1))}{x-1}} = \sqrt{\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln(1+(x-1))}{x-1}} = \sqrt{1}=1
$$

Can you conclude?

Comment: Well,yes, problem is indeed at $a=1$,so it seemed weird to me trying to determine the order of function with respect to ${1\over x-2}$.So, to conclude, if **c** is a point where my function is problematic, I should try to determine the order with respect to ${1\over x-c}$.Moreover, if I am determining the order of $f(x)={1\over \sqrt \ln x}$ ,shouldn't I write $$\lim_{x\to1+}{(x-1)^{1\over2}\over \sqrt{\ln (1+(x-1))}}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{x-1}{\ln(1+(x-1))}}=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to1+}(\frac {\ln(1+(x-1))}{x-1})^-1}=\sqrt1=1$$ ?

Comment: You seem to have a problem with the superscript, but yes. But that's the same... if $f/g\to 1$ and $g>0$, then $g/f\to 1$ and $f>0$. @TuranNəsibli

Comment: I'm trying to fix the problem,and thank you for the help.

Comment: @TuranNəsibli You're welcome! (for the Latex issue: us ``a^{-1}``, with braces.)